# Why is zero the only infinitesimal real number?

Tags: real-analysis, infinitesimals

I am currently  reading [Elementary Calculus: An Infinitesimal Approach](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ross/Infinitesimals/KeislerText.html) by H. Jerome  Keisler and was wondering if someone could help me with an aspect treated in the book.

On [page 24](https://books.google.com/books?id=8NTCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA24#v=onepage) he says a number $\varepsilon$ is said to be *infinitely small* or *infinitesimal* if $$-a< \varepsilon < a$$ for every positive real number $a$. He then says the only real number that is infinitesimal is zero.

I really don't get that. What I understand is that in order for a number to be considered infinitely small it has to be bigger then $-a$ and smaller then $a$. Well if I take $a$ to be $-2$ that means that $-1$ would be infinitesimal since it is bigger than $-2$ but smaller then $2$. So then how can zero be the only real number that satisfies that condition?

Comment: Maybe some of this question is missing? If so, please edit to add the additional information.

Comment: Hi Ken, i typed the whole question however for some reason its only displaying a part of it.

Comment: I think it should work fine now

Comment: Suppose I have fixed the number $\epsilon$. Then $\epsilon$ is infinitesimal if and only if for *every* $a \in \mathbb{R}, a > 0$, we have that $- a < \epsilon < a$. For example, $-2 < -1 < + 2$, but NOT $-1/2 < -1 < + 1/2$. So $-1$ is not infinitesimal.

Comment: AJY thank you i got it.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: The naming, as explained by @CameronWilliams, also drove me crazy on my first Calculus course until one day, after a lot of thinking about it, I came to that conclusion. If only I was aware of math.stackexchange.com back then (;

Comment: @samuel, you should now choose the answer that helped you the most and "accept" it by clicking on the big check mark.

Comment: @ martin sleziak thank you i will surely look into that

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia indeed. I never thought that it would be that fast and helpful glad i posted my question here.

Comment: @alexis alright thank you for the info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example of taking $a$ to be $2$ and concluding that $1$ is infinitesimal since it is between $-2$ and $2$ is not a good example.

The reason for this is that the definition of an infinitesimal $\varepsilon$ is that $-a \leq \varepsilon \leq a$ **for every** positive real number $a$.  You just picked some positive real number.  This has to be true for every positive real number.  That means $\varepsilon$ needs to be in $[-2, 2]$ and in $[-1, 1]$ and in $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$ and in $[-\frac{1}{1000000}, \frac{1}{1000000}]$, and so on.  That same $\varepsilon$ has to be in all of these at the same time to be an infinitesimal.

The only *real* number that satisfies that it is between $-a$ and $a$ for every real $a > 0$ is $\varepsilon = 0$.

So any number $\varepsilon$ other than $0$ that satisfies $-a \leq \varepsilon \leq a$ for every $a > 0$ real cannot itself be a *real* number, but there are plenty of infinitesimals that aren't real numbers.  As we discussed, $0$ is the only number that's both real and infinitesimal.

Comment: Wow thank a lot.That was quick and very helpful especially the examples.

Comment: @samuel You're welcome!

Answer (score 21):

The point is that it is greater than $-a$ and less than $a$ **for every** $a$. So if you consider $e = -1$, you're correct that $-2 < -1 < 2$ but what about $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$? Clearly $-1$ does not lie between $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$. Likewise, if you had *any* non-zero real number $x$, $x$ does not lie between $-\frac{x}{2}$ and $\frac{x}{2}$. Thus the only *real* infinitesimal is $0$.

Comment: Cameron Williams thank you between your answer and the answer from user 46944 i understood what was meant. Thank a bunch

Comment: You're very welcome. Happy to help. Please don't hesitate to ask questions in the future! You're off to a great start.